# modal popup reopened javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have been trying to do a JS Fiddle of this but cant seem to make it happen as my javascript loads its html via PHP controller.

However.

I have a JQuery UI modal popup window contained the appropriate view which is a from. I have some JS on this form that shows and hides divs depending on a select box:

```
  function showDiv(divName)
{
document.getElementById(divName).style.display='';
}
function hideDiv(divName)
{
document.getElementById(divName).style.display='none';
}
function toggleOpDiv(showID)
{
if (showID == '1')
    {
    hideDiv('plus');
    hideDiv('mult');
    showDiv('perc');
    }
else if (showID == '2')
    {
    hideDiv('mult');
    hideDiv('perc');
    showDiv('plus');
    }
else if (showID == '3')
    {
    hideDiv('plus');
    hideDiv('perc');
    showDiv('mult');
    }
else
    {
    hideDiv('plus');
    hideDiv('mult');
    hideDiv('perc');
    }
}
```

this is then triggered quite simply by:

```
<select id="frm_source" name="operator" onchange="toggleOpDiv(this.value)">
                            <option value="1">Percentage</option>
                            <option value="2">Plus/Minus</option>
                            <option value="3">Multiplier</option>
                    </select>
```

This is working as I'd expect, however when I close the box and re-open it, no JS is working at all.

I have read that this is due to Ajax firing? How can I reset this on the form load?

Answer (score 0):

```
function showDiv(divName)
{
document.getElementById(divName).style.display = '';
}
```

I think you meant setting display to block like this instead:

```
document.getElementById(divName).style.display = 'block';
```

I guess there have to be some error in your code, which is the cause why something is broken with your javascript.

Try to use FireBug to check whether your site doesn't contain any errors before dialog open and thereafter.

Even if your HTML comes dynamically from outside, try to put this as static html in a jsfiddle, which will help you to track and solve your problem.

Other than that, it will be guesswork without seeing full example/jsfiddle.